# How to insert data into a table in testcafe

Tags: testing

I have a page with with a table. I want to make an automation test with testcafe + javascript and insert values into the rows.

Tried with addCustomMethods as in https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/extending-selectors.html but it doesnot seem to work as it doesnot get the table and returns undefined.

So how do I insert values  to multiple rows in a table?

Comment: Figured the solution out by using selectors alone and iterating the table. Omitted the client fucntion